# Chain Rule: Is the notation $\frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx}$ accurate?

Tags: derivatives, notation, education

My question is if it is okay / mathematically rigorous to write the Chain Rule like that (the Leibniz way). I thought that $dx$, etc. do not follow the rules of algebra and cannot be treated as such. For example, I write $\int 1\, dx$, rather than $\int 1 \,dx$, and I write $\int \frac{dx}{a}$ instead of $\int \frac{1}{a}\, dx$.

So, is it correct to say $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx}$ and, in essence, have the $\frac{du}{du}$ cancel to $1$?

(If my notion of $dx$ is not correct, I would also like an explanation of what *really* that is)

edit: Is it the same deal with $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$?

Comment: With the standard meaning, it's wrong.

Comment: Treating differentials like fractions is kind of like how a classical  mathematician would look on a calculation involving the root of a negative number. Clearly you get the right answer every time, but there's something awfully wrong with how you get there.

Comment: Leibniz notation is great and can help you keep track of the chain rule easily but every calculus instructor should explicitly state that it is only notation and that $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ is not a fraction but only a notation. It is very suggestive notation, but that is all it is. Neither $dy$ nor $dx$ exist as independent entities. You can ONLY take the entire thing together to make meaningful notation. I feel like Leibniz notation should be stricken from first year calculus texts for this reason, despite how useful it is..

Comment: I dislike this notation because two different functions, $y$ and $y \circ u$, are both being denoted by $y$. Moreover, the Leibniz notation doesn't make it clear that $y'$ is evaluated at $u(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of differentials (in the single-variable case), $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is the unique scalar with the property that $\frac{dy}{dx}dx = dy$.

$\frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx}$ therefore has the property that

$$\frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx} dx = \frac{dy}{du} du = dy $$

therefore $\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx}$.

You can't really justify the result by rearranging the expression like you would with fractions (e.g. by combining them into a single 'fraction'), which is why people mean when they say things like "you can't just cancel them". However, you can still prove (again this only makes sense in the single-variable case) that rearrangements are equal: e.g.

$$ \frac{dw}{dx} \frac{dy}{dz}  = \frac{dw}{dz} \frac{dy}{dx} $$

(note that you could use this identity to prove your identity, because $\frac{du}{du} = 1$)

Answer (score 0):

The notation $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} * \frac{du}{dx}$ is valid. However, you cannot prove the chain rule just by "cancelling" the two $du$'s; it doesn't work that way.

Comment: "it doesn't work that way" -- care to elaborate?

Comment: No, the notation makes no sense.

Comment: @GitGud See [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChainRule.html) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) - both use this notation. In the end, arguing about notation is unimportant, and notation is defined by what people commonly use. It's just a language used to express math.

Comment: @user92774: When you write $\frac{dy}{dx}$, you aren't really writing a fraction consisting of $dy$ divided by $dx$. It's just a notation defined as the limit of the difference quotient as $x$ approaches a certain point.

Comment: No, the notation is defined, period. It has nothing to do with what people use. When one writes $f=gh$, what one means is $f(a)=g(a)h(a)$, for all $a$ somewhere. This is how it is. Particularizing to $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy}{du} \dfrac{du}{dx}$ gives $\dfrac{dy}{dx}(a) = \dfrac{dy}{du}(a) \dfrac{du}{dx}(a)$ and that's not at all what's intended.

Comment: Are you suggesting that Wolfram MathWorld is wrong?

Comment: @Tony They are abusing the notation and abuses of notation are wrong. Concluding: yes, they are wrong.

Comment: @Git Gud: Then I hope you don't use both of $sin^2$ and $sin^{-1}$.

Comment: @user2345215 I use neither, but $\sin ^{-1}$ has no problems.

Answer (score 0):

There is a $C$ which **looks like** $A/B$ (suppose) in some german notation. And now in some rule you denote some value by $C$ and others by $A$ and $B$ and $C = A/B$ is the rule. You won't say you broke the notation $C$ into $A/B$ because it was looking so.

You will deal more such cases in integration.

Answer (score 0):

The relation
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx}$$

requires that $u$ has a nonzero relationship with $x$ and $y$.  This doesn't have to be explicitly stated when the chain rule is written as 
  $$D_x f(g(x)) = f'g(x) \cdot g'(x)$$

Example:

Consider using $g = \text{gravitational force}$ and $r = \text{distance}$.  You might know:

$$g = G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$$

What if $u$ is your temperature?  Perhaps your temperature does not change based on your location.
$$\frac{du}{dr} = 0$$
$$\frac{dg}{du} = 0$$

If you applied the chain rule without realizing that $u$ is an independent variable, you'd get:

$$\begin{align}\frac{dg}{dr} &= \frac{dg}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dr}\\
&= 0 \cdot 0 \end{align}$$

...and I think we can agree that gravitational force is not universally constant.  So when using the differential form of the chain rule, make sure you are not using an independent variable.